# SQL Logic Check

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm new to SQL/Teradata. The numbers I got from the 2nd query are not what I expected, which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong.

I have two conditions I want to count by:

Condition 1:

```
owner_id= 'x'
AND
acct_mgr_user_id= 'x'
```

Condition 2 (All other Permutations):

```
owner_id<> 'x'
acct_mgr_user_id= 'x'


owner_id= 'x'
acct_mgr_user_id<> 'x'


owner_id<> 'x'
acct_mgr_user_id<> 'x'
```

**Query for Condition 1:**

```
SELECT Count(acct_id) FROM nr_sf_acct
WHERE owner_id= 'x'
AND acct_mgr_user_id= 'x'
AND is_sf_acct_del_y_n= 'n';
```

I think this one is wrong . . .

**Query for Condition 2**

```
SELECT Count(acct_id) FROM nr_sf_acct
WHERE owner_id<> 'x'
OR acct_mgr_user_id<> 'x'
AND is_sf_acct_del_y_n= 'n';
```

In the query for set 2 I want to return a count for "all other permutations" as noted above.

'x' refers to a unique Id number within the table.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to negate the 1st condition, so do:

```
WHERE (NOT (owner_id = 'x' AND acct_mgr_user_id = 'x')) AND (is_sf_acct_del_y_n = 'n')
```

or:

```
WHERE (owner_id <> 'x' OR acct_mgr_user_id <> 'x') AND (is_sf_acct_del_y_n = 'n')
```

Comment: WHERE (owner_id <> 'x' OR acct_mgr_user_id <> 'x') AND (is_sf_acct_del_y_n = 'n')

That works, but the WHERE NOT version returned a much lower number for some reason. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The operator NOT has higher precedence than AND so I assume that the 2 boolean expressions are equivalent. If this is not the case in Terradata then the 1st case needs parentheses.